# Плохой код или нет?

Tags: php

```
<?php
if (isset($post['attachment']['photo']['src_xxbig'])) {
    $img = $post['attachment']['photo']['src_xxbig'];
} else
    if (isset($post['attachment']['photo']['src_xbig'])) {
        $img = $post['attachment']['photo']['src_xbig'];
    } else
        if (isset($post['attachment']['photo']['src_big'])) {
            $img = $post['attachment']['photo']['src_big'];
        } else
            $img = false;
?>
```

Можно ли как нибудь "уменьшить код" ?.

Comment: лучше empty вместо isset

Comment: Вопрос для какого-нибудь форума, а не для stackoverflow!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

сделал так

```
            $scr = [
                'src_xxbig',
                'src_xbig',
                'src_big',
                ];

            foreach ($scr as $v) {
                if (array_key_exists($v, $post['attachment']['photo'])) {
                    $img = $post['attachment']['photo'][$v];
                    break;
                }
            }
```

Comment: А что мешало использовать isset? if (isset($post['attachment']['photo'][$v]) {...

Comment: забыли дефолтное значение в начале дать: `$img = false;`

Comment: `foreach(['src_xxbig', 'src_xbig', 'src_big'] as $v)` не работает?

Answer (score 8):

Один фрагмент можно так записать:

```
$photo = $post['attachment']['photo'];
if (isset($photo['src_xxbig'])) {
    $img = $photo['src_xxbig'];
} else if (isset($photo['src_xbig'])) {
    $img = $photo['src_xbig'];
} else if (isset($photo['src_big'])) {
    $img = $photo['src_big'];
} else $img = false;
```

Если подобная логика повторяется несколько раз, можно вынести её в функцию:

```
$img = fallback(
    $post['attachment']['photo'],
    ['src_xxbig','src_xbig','src_big'],
    false
);

function fallback( $src, $keys, $default) {
    foreach( $keys as $key) {
        if( array_key_exists( $src[$key]) return $src[ $key];
    }
    return $default;
}
```

В первом варианте использовался `isset()`, а во втором – `array_key_exists()` потому, что в частном 1-м случае понятно, что там не ожидаются значения `NULL`. В функции, как более универсальном решении, лучше предусмотреть такой вариант. Разница в том, что для `$arr[$key] = NULL` (значение элемента с искомым ключём – NULL)  `isset()` вернёт FALSE, как будто такого ключа нет, а `array_key_exists()` – TRUE, как и положено, ведь ключ определён.

Answer (score 0):

```php
$img = $post['attachment']['photo']['src_xxbig']
?? $post['attachment']['photo']['src_xbig']
?? $post['attachment']['photo']['src_big']
?? false
```